# Solution set for $ 0 < | x - c | < \delta$. Is $|x - c| < \delta$ equivalent to $0 \leq | x - c | < \delta$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $c$ be a real number constant, and $\delta > 0$ and also a real number. Consider the following:

$$ |x - c| < \delta \label{1}\tag{1}$$

$$0 \leq | x - c | < \delta \label{2}\tag{2}$$

Is \eqref{1} equivalent to \eqref{2}?

I think it is, because any absolute value must be $\geq 0$ by definition.

The question came up while trying to figure out the solution set for:

$$ 0 < | x - c | < \delta \label{3}\tag{3}$$

I know the solution set for \eqref{1} can be found as follows:

$$ |x - c| < \delta \Longleftrightarrow - \delta < x - c < \delta \Longleftrightarrow c - \delta < x < c + \delta \Longleftrightarrow (c - \delta, c + \delta) \label{4}\tag{4}$$

If \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} are equivalent, then the solution set for \eqref{3} can be found by subtracting $\{ c \}$ from the solution found in \eqref{4}:

$$( c - \delta, c + \delta) \setminus \{ c \} = (c - \delta, c) \cup (c, c + \delta)$$

Is my reasoning correct? Is there a better or more efficient way to find the solution set of \eqref{3}?

Comment: In short, (1) and (2) are equivalent, and neither is equivalent to (3). If $c$ and $\delta>0$ are fixed, then the solution set for (1) and (2) is $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ whereas the solution set for (3) is $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\backslash\{c\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent (by definition). Indeed, the solution set of $(3)$ thus equals the solution set of $(2)$ minus $\{c\}$ (i.e. $]c-\delta,c+\delta[\setminus\{c\}$.)

Note that the same thing also holds for complex numbers (or more generally also for Banach spaces where you use a general norm in the place of the absolute value.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, and there is a reason for the two expressions. To verify that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$, you have to ignore the value, or even the existence of a value, of $f(c)$. In other words, the limit is what happens when you get close to $x=c$, not what happens at $x=c$. To prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$, You need to show that $f(c)$ exists and that  $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c)$.